# The requested URL returned error: 403 как исправить?

Tags: git, github, git-push

При `git push` получаю такую ошибку:

> remote: Permission to 21Sirius/my-first-blog.git denied to 21Sirius.
> fatal: «https://github.com/21Sirius/my-first-blog.git/»
> недоступно: The requested URL returned error: 403

Искал конечно же до этого решение в интернете, но у всех проблема из-за двух аккаунтов, а у меня это первый и единственный аккаунт на *Github*. 
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: ну так а доступ-то настроен?

Comment: репозиторий пустой. добавьте туда какой-нибудь файл. тогда появится ссылка на скачивание... а так трудно проверить вашу ссылку

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/about-ssh

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо за отклик.Через четыре дня поиска решения проблемы,я почти заговорил на  хинди, но все оказалось намного проще.При создании токена на GitHub не выбрал области действия. На радостях от возможного нового решения,просто выбрал всё,разбираться буду позже)
(Помог с решением @sergey-kuznetsov на Habr.com)